# Render ASP.NET MVC PartialView Using AngularJS

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I am trying to integrate [Report Viewer for MVC](https://reportviewerformvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started) to my angular app with ASP.NET MVC 5.

REPORT:

View/Report/Index.cshtml

```
@model JET.Shop.Common.Models.ReportRequestModel
@using ReportViewerForMvc;
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Report", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Start Date</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, string.Format("{0:d}", DateTime.Now), new { @id = "startDate", @class = "datefield", type = "date" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>End Date</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate, string.Format("{0:d}", DateTime.Now), new { @id = "endDate", @class = "datefield", type = "date" })
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Generate" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)
    </div>
</div>
```

ReportController

```
public class ReportController : Controller
{
    // GET: Report
    public ActionResult Index(ReportType reportType = ReportType.SalesOrderList)
    {
        ReportRequestModel model = new ReportRequestModel();

        model.Type = reportType;
        model.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
        model.EndDate = DateTime.Now;

        return PartialView(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ReportRequestModel request)
    {
        List<ReportParameter> reportParams = new List<ReportParameter>();
        ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
        reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

        SalesOrdersListDataSet salesOrderDataSet = new SalesOrdersListDataSet();
        salesOrderDataSet.SalesOrder.AddSalesOrderRow(Guid.NewGuid(), DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), 500, 60, 440, "Complete");
        salesOrderDataSet.SalesOrder.AddSalesOrderRow(Guid.NewGuid(), DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), 100, 12, 88, "Complete");

        ReportDataSource reportDataSource1 = new ReportDataSource();
        reportDataSource1.Name = "Report"; //Name of the report dataset in our .RDLC file
        reportDataSource1.Value = salesOrderDataSet.SalesOrder;

        reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1);
        reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "JET.Shop.WebApp.Reports.SalesOrderListReport.rdlc";
        reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParams);

        ViewBag.ReportViewer = reportViewer;

        return PartialView(request);
    }
}
```

RouteConfig

```
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "ReportController",
               url: "Report/Index/{reportType}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Report", action = "Index", reportType = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

$RouteProvider

```
.when("/Report", {
                    templateUrl: "/Report/Index",
                    controller: "ReportController",
                    loginRequired: true,
                    requiredRoles: ["Admin"]
                })
```

I basically wanna try to render this report viewer but I got stuck with getting HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error on the console.

I did some random trial and error and found out that if I make my Report/Index.cshtml contain nothing but plain HTML (no razor) it renders. But when I include my @model statement on the view I get HTTP 500. Can anyone help me with this issue? Breakpoints to my controller (GET Index) works fine.

FYI I navigate to the Report page by accessing it directly via URL on the browser for quick testing only.

Any suggestions on how should I approach this? My main goal is to display a ReportViewer because I can work from there once it gets rendered on the view.

Report/Index.cshtml with plain HTML that works..

```
@*@model JET.Shop.Common.Models.ReportRequestModel
@using ReportViewerForMvc;*@

<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @*@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Report", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Start Date</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, string.Format("{0:d}", DateTime.Now), new { @id = "startDate", @class = "datefield", type = "date" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>End Date</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate, string.Format("{0:d}", DateTime.Now), new { @id = "endDate", @class = "datefield", type = "date" })
                </div>
            }*@
            THIS WORKS FINE!
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Generate" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        @*@Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)*@
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question,

I ended up not using the report viewer at all. I just created an MVC controller that generates an Excel/PDF from a crystal report.